# WPF How to change DataGrid corners and how to remove empty field in dataGrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, cornerradius

I have few problem with DataGrid style.

1. I need it change two corners, when I try to do that by example my data disappear, its possible do that with my code?
   My code is:

   ```
   ...<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
       <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFF"/>
       <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
       <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#E6E6E6"/>
   </Style>

   <DataGridTextColumn x:Key="price"  Header="Price, €  " FontFamily="Arial" Width="0.3*" Binding="{Binding adress}" IsReadOnly="True"
                        FontSize="18" FontWeight="Normal" Foreground="#4D4D4D">
       <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
           <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
               <Setter Property="Width" Value="25"/>
               <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
               <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
           </Style>
       </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
       <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
           <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
               <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFF"/>
               <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
               <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#E6E6E6"/>
               <Setter Property="Height" Value="35"/>
               <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
               <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
               <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
               <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
               <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
               <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
           </Style>
       </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
   </DataGridTextColumn>

   <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
       <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
       <Style.Triggers>
           <Trigger Property="DataGrid.IsSelected" Value="True">
               <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
           </Trigger>
       </Style.Triggers>
   </Style> 
   <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="#FFD65E" />
   ```

   ```
   <Grid>
   <DataGrid x:Name="lbPersonList" Margin="30,98,362,30" AlternationCount="2" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                 RowHeight="42" GridLinesVisibility="None" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#E6E6E6" CanUserAddRows="False" 
             HeadersVisibility="Column" >
       <DataGrid.Columns>
           <StaticResource ResourceKey="product"/>
           <StaticResource ResourceKey="unit price"/>
           <StaticResource ResourceKey="quantity"/>
           <StaticResource ResourceKey="price"/>
       </DataGrid.Columns>
   </DataGrid>
   ```
  2.

How to remove this empty field, I removed last row so this empty field is not row ?

[image]

Comment: You want corners for entire DataGrid or Cell??

Answer (score 1):

You have to edit the default ControlTemplate of DataGrid by adding `<Border>` to the root grid control

```
     <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">                
                        <Border x:Name="Border" CornerRadius="13" Background="#232323" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
    <Grid>
                        ........
                        .......
    </Grid>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
</Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

you can find the default ControlTemplate of DataGrid at
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278066(v=vs.95).aspx